# .Net XmlSerializer - Check before writing

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

Is there a way to tell the XmlSerializer to update the xml element instead of overriding them?

For example, if I have 2 applications that write in the same xml file with

> xmlSerializer.Serialize(...)

When the second application will save (serialize), it will overrides change done by the first application. So that's why I'm asking if the XmlSerializer can do a check to update the object being serialize instead of only writing the file with no check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlSerializer will exclusively write a new XML tree. It cannot be configured to merge output into an existing DOM, or do any other kind of checking.

Comment: Is there any .Net or third party similar classes that can do that?

Comment: @Melursus you could write to a second file and just compare before using File.Replace?